# Display ArcSDE-metadata in Browser

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, metadata, browser

Is there a good tool / technique to display ArcSDE-metadata in a webbrowser?

We want to provide user without GIS-knowledge with a user friendly tool to explore our SDE metadata catalog. We are using the inspire-profile for metadata input. They just need to explore the properties of the metadata, they don't need to see the data itself.

I am currently experimenting with geoportal to allow user without arcgis explore our metadata catalog. But i feel like it is to complex for non-gis users, with all the categories etc.

I have also looked at geonetwork, but there seems to be no way to automate the update from database to  server and i also had issue's with the import of metadata xml from exported form arccatalog.

Answer (score 1):

SDE metadata catalog is quite different from FGDC metadata.
You might consider creating an xml view of your sde data catalog and serve that to an esri simplified template.
I just found this link that might be of help.
[Chris North from esri](http://www.isotc211.org/WorkshopMontreal/Presentations/North.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

http://geocat.net/bridge is an easy tool to convert ArcSDE-metadata to iso19139-inspire metadata, and optionally publish it to http://geonetwork-opensource.org
Other options in bridge are publishing data from ArcMap to geoserver/mapserver.

You also might want to have a look at http://www.esri.nl/geosticker

Comment: I aware of these solutions. My users believe geoportal and geo-network are to complex for our goals (and I agree). We just want to display the metadata in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own solution:

I discovered, i can use the GP-tool XSLTransform from the toolbox conversion/metadata to  write to HTML.

With some simple python i can now traverse my database an publish it to my webserver.
I also wrote some extra code to generate a sort of index-page as well.

For example:
With this tool i can convert a the metadata of a single dataset to html:

```
import arcpy, os, sys

inData = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) 
outHtml = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

def main():
    iDir = arcpy.GetInstallInfo("desktop")["InstallDir"]
    xslt= iDir + r"Metadata\Stylesheets\ArcGIS.xsl"
    arcpy.XSLTransform_conversion( inData , xslt, outHtml , "#")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```